# PyTorch new model function leaking gpu memory

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I had a perfectly working code, until I had to do some modification to make it more flexible with some hyperparameters.

In the bellow snippet you can see my forward function which before worked using the 2 commented lines. As I needed more flexibility in the `nn.Linear` from `self.classifier`, I made the function `classifierAdaptive()` which does the same thing but allows some parameters to change in the `nn.Linear`.

Previous GPU Ram usage was around 7GB/11GB, now I am running out of GPU Ram and I can't figure out why. I can't think of any variable to cause memory issues.

Edit:

The dataset is of images of size 2200x2200, from which I make small cuts to train on. These cuts are currently hardcoded as in 6 * 6.

Desired behaviour will be to only have 1 `nn.Linear` which would work for all `img.shapes`. However, as `@jsho` said, the mode maybe is creating too many layers instead of just 1 and overwriting?

I cannot include the entire code for debugging. It would be too much. But if needed [can be seen here](https://github.com/CatalinOAlexandru/SRGAN-PyTorch/blob/master/srgan_pytorch/model.py) without the bellow code modification.

```
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(512 * 6 * 6, 1024),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        nn.Linear(1024, 1),
        nn.Sigmoid()
    )

def classifierAdaptive(self,img):
    out = torch.flatten(img, 1)
    outLinear = nn.Linear(512 * img.shape[2] * img.shape[3], 1024).cuda()
    out = outLinear(out).cuda()
    out = self.lrelu(out) # self.lrelu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True)
    out = self.dens2(out) # self.dens2 = nn.Linear(1024, 1)
    out = self.sig(out) # self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()

    return out

def forward(self, x):
    out = self.features(x)

    # out = torch.flatten(out, 1)
    # out = self.classifier(out)

    out = self.classifierAdaptive(out)

    return out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new layer for every image with a different size, which not only will not work, but every new layer will have its set of parameters which it saves in GPU memory, and so you will quickly run out of memory space. This is a usual problem in image processing due to the fixed size of linear layers as opposed to the dynamic H,W dimensions of the convolution layers. The only real way to fix it is to reshape your images to the same size prior to putting them in the network (look at  torch.nn.functional.interpolate or cv2.resize) or to use a convolution with a kernel size of 1 (effectively a linear layer) and do some global average/max pooling to shrink the data to the same size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to add some clarifications. My images are all 2200x2200, however, as data preparation in the model I make cuts of these images of for example 96x96 which is a hyperparameter.  Therefore, without changing the model every time, I want to be able to edit what cut size the model support with the new functions. Before it supported only 96x96 or close to it. The entire model is already in cuda(), but I had some errors with the 2 lines above, and I had to manually add them to cuda(). So the new layer should be the same at every epoch.

Edit: Pressed send too early.

Comment: Yes, but you can't create new layers in the forward call of a torch nn module without creating a brand new set of parameters because it will create a brand new layer EVERY CALL! It doesn't even matter if all of your images are the exact same size. I must say that I did I understand your problem, and my solutions provided above are the most suitable to fix it (that I thought of!).

Comment: "it will create a brand new layer EVERY CALL" - I see! Got it now, thank you, @jhso